# Googlemap shows wrong location

Tags: android, gps, location

Im trying to make a tracking application.

The problem is that the location I get from the gps locationlistner is true but the location showing in the googlemap is wrong by atleast 20m.
This is shown in the picture below, red line is drawn from first know location to updated location 10seconds later. So to be clear I got almost a perfect location after 10seconds but still the blue icon dont change to it. (NOTE, it is zoomed to max)

[image: googlemap]

Code:

```
public class LocationHandler{

    //Location handlers
    private LocationManager locationManager = null;

    //Keep track of current location
    private LatLng currentLatLng = null;    
    private Location currentLocation = null;

    //Bools
    private Boolean gpsLock = false;
    private Boolean gpsEnable = false;

    public LocationHandler(Activity activity) {

        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);

        // Showing status
        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, activity, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else {

            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            locationManager = (LocationManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Check type of location service
            if(locationManager != null){

                try{gpsEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

                if(gpsEnable){
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, gpsLocationListener);
                }

            }

        }
    }

    public void stopLocationUpdates() {

        if(gpsLocationListener != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(gpsLocationListener); 
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the currentLocation
     */
    public Location getCurrentLocation() {
        return currentLocation;
    }

    /**
     * @return the latLng
     */
    public LatLng getCurrentLatLng() {
        return currentLatLng;
    }


    /**
     * @return the gpsLock
     */
    public Boolean getGpsLock() {
        return gpsLock;
    }


    public void setLatLng(Location location){

        if(location.getAccuracy() < 50){
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();

            // Getting longitude of the current location
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();


            // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
            currentLatLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            currentLocation = location; 
        }

    }

    private LocationListener gpsLocationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){}
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){}       

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            gpsLock = true;
            setLatLng(location);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blue dot does not neccessarily perfectly match the coordinates you got by the location listener.
The blue dot is filtered, sucht that it avoids unrealistic jumps.
Such jumps could happen when you don't move.

Propably you are sitting in a building or surounded by high buildings.
If you move (walk down the street) the dot will update to match the coodinates.
Further nobody told that the streets in google maps are always at the correct position.
The map companies that deliver maps to google (TomTom and Navteq) state that the accuracy within cities is within 5m, and in rural region 20m.

However in your case I asume - as said above - that it is a filtering of the blue dot. (On ios the blue dot even does an extrapolation into the future if you are driving).

An acuracy deviation in cities can reach about 30m when you are outside, if you are inside a building sitting near the window, the offset may exceed 60m.

Answer (score 0):

The accuracy of GPS is dependent on a variety of factors like:

1. Number of satellites sending data to the sensor(more the better)
2. How powerful is the GPS chip(handheld devices are not so powerful).
3. The weather conditions(clear sky)
4. Obstacles like inside building,etc.
5. Your geographical position

As you mentioned **atleast by 20 meters** I think it is not so far off. I have seen gps sensor being off by more than 3 kilometers on a cloudy rainy day in my app. Typically, the accuracy is within 50 meters. You can use google maps app to check relative accuracy between your and google's app.

Comment: But the GPS location gathered by the listener is correct, very accurate. It's the blue dot that isn't placed on the spot I get from the GPS listener.

Comment: -1: 3. is wrong: GPS is not dependent on rainy or clear sky (it is dependent on your point 5:  free view to sky), 1: is partly correct, its is  more the angle to the satelites not onyl the number. 2: is to simple; 3km offset may happen but is extremely rare, in most cases the cause is the app that got a cell tower locationing fix, and that cannot distinguish between a fix received by GPS or cell tower /wlan

Comment: @AlexWien see this answer http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11116/does-gps-signal-quality-depend-on-the-chip-manufacturer-does-it-depend-on-weath

Comment: @IllegalArgument I have read the answer in the link: You have to distinguish between ionospheric wheather (=sun disturbs!), as they wrote and which is true,  and rain or cloudy as you wrote. That is not ionospheric wheather!